# Coldfusion create Json with ArrayAppend & cfloop

Tags: arrays, json, struct, coldfusion

I am trying to create a JSON structure to send API to a Mexican invoice provider (cfdi 3.3). I already have a function with the values ​​of the items, with cfloop. The question is that I don't know how to insert in the same structure the other values ​​that are not within the array `"Items:"`, such as payment_type, customer, etc

This is the example of API request

---

```
curl https://www.facturapi.io/v1/invoices \
  -u "sk_test_API_KEY:" \
  -H "Content-Type: application / json" \
  -d '{
    "customer": "58e93ionede86eb318b0197456",
    "items": [{
      "quantity": 2,
      "product": "58e93ionede86eb318b0197454"
    }],
    "payment_form": "06",
    "folio_number": 914,
    "series": "A"
  } '
```

**I want to get a structure like this:**

```
{
  "customer": "77e93ionede86eb318b0197456",
  "items": [
    {
      "quantity": 2,
      "product": "99e93etimee86eb318b0191111"
    },
    {
      "quantity": 5,
      "product": "88e55etimee86eb999b0192222"
    }
  ],
  "payment_form": "06",
  "folio_number": 914,
  "series": "A"
}
```

This is my code (cffunction)

---

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset #dsnvtasmart# = "popmart">

    <cffunction name="result" access="remote" 
            returntype="array"
            returnformat="JSON" 
            hint="it is the text">

         <cfset #dsnvtasmart# = "popmart">
         <cfquery name="qProd" datasource="#dsnvtasmart#">
            SELECT det_ordenp.cant AS quantity
                    , det_ordenp.api_id_prod AS product
            FROM    det_ordenp
            WHERE   det_ordenp.id_orden = #worden#
         </cfquery>

        <!--- 
            **---Other values Json Struct.--------**
        --->    
        <cfset customer =#77e93ionede86eb318b0197456#>
        <cfset payment_form = '06'>
        <cfset folio_number = 914>
        <cfset series = 'A'>

        <cfloop query="qProd">
            <cfset var empStruct = {"quantity":#qProd.quantity#, "product":#qProd.product#}>
            <cfset arrayAppend (result, empStruct)>
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn result>
   </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

At the moment, with this code, I am only getting:

```
[
  {
    "quantity": 6,
    "product": "5d5307eb8a6ce057e78b32be"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 37,
    "product": "5d53080d8a6ce057e78b32c0"
  }
]
```

I have no idea how to include in `empStruct`, the values ​​of :

```
{
  "customer": "77e93ionede86eb318b0197456",
  "payment_form": "06",
  "folio_number": 914,
  "series": "A"
}
```

I hope my question is readable, if anyone has a suggestion I would appreciate it.

Comment: What's your CF version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you are only returning an array with the items. Change your function's `returnType` to `struct` and modify your code like this:

```
<cffunction ... returnType="struct" returnFormat="JSON">

        ...
    </cfquery>

    <cfset var response             = {}>
    <cfset response["customer"]     = "77e93ionede86eb318b0197456">
    <cfset response["items"]        = []>
    <cfset response["payment_form"] = "06">
    <cfset response["folio_number"] = 914>
    <cfset response["series"]       = "A">

    <cfloop query="qProd">
        <cfset var item = {}>
        <cfset item["quantity"] = qProd.quantity>
        <cfset item["product"]  = qProd.product>
        <cfset arrayAppend(response["items"], item)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn response>
</cffunction>
```

- I used `...` to skip some code.
- Using the bracket notation for structs (like `response["customer"]`) will guarantee the case of the key, while using the dot notation (like `response.customer`) may result in being serialized as `"CUSTOMER":` later.
- `arrayAppend(array, element)` is the ugly version of `array.add(element)` (all CF versions), i.e. `array.append(element)` (CF2016+)

Comment: Thanks for your support, i see your code and now I know what I have to do,I really appreciate your help and thanks